# Design of a double A-arm suspension

Tags: suspension, car, automotive-design, control-arm

Can a double A-arm suspension have its arms bent as shown in the sketch below?

The sketch is taken to be viewed from the the front.

[image: double wishbone]

Comment: You are suggesting the arms are bent at the circles and the points at the trapezoid is where the a-arms move (pivot)?

Answer (score 3):

If pictures can tell a story ... my answer is sure:

[image]